# Grabbing content from paragraph element and passing to OpenAI API for processing

Tags: javascript, html, openai-api

I am building a script using the OpenAI API that grabs text content from a clicked on paragraph element in index.html and passes to a separate script in explanation.html where the content from the clicked on paragraph in index.html is passed to the script in explanation.html where OpenAI processes the content as "What does this sentence mean?" + p content and returns an output that is an explanation of the p content provided to the OpenAI API.

Here is the code I am working with:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function showExplanation(element) {
        const sentence = element.textContent.trim();

        fetch('/explanation.html?sentence=' + encodeURIComponent(sentence))
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(explanation => {
            const win = window.open('', '_blank');
            win.document.write('<html><head><title>Explanation</title></head><body><p>' + explanation + '</p></body></html>');
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="showExplanation(this)">Sentence 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showExplanation(this)">Sentence 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showExplanation(this)">Sentence 3</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

explanation.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Explanation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Loading...</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const sentence = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('sentence');
      const api_key = 'YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY_HERE';

      fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'prompt': "What does this sentence mean? " + sentence,
          'max_tokens': 512,
          'n': 1,
          'stop': '.'
        })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(output => {
          const explanation = output.choices[0].text;
          const pElement = document.createElement('p');
          pElement.textContent = explanation;
          document.body.innerHTML = '';
          document.body.appendChild(pElement);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried running the code on My live site and it seems to be getting stuck with a "Loading..." response. The static "Loading..." in the code is not being replaced by the dynamic explanation being fetched from the OpenAI API using the provided prompt + sentence extracted from the p tag. Any ideas on how to get this script to return the dynamic explanation?

EDIT:

I edited the code to reflect the localStorage suggestion provided by Kokodoko. I also replaced the API url with the url provided by Kokodoko. I am now getting responses from the OpenAI API however they are garbled and the output does not reflect the answers provided in GPT4 using the same prompt.

Here is the new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function showExplanation(element) {
        const sentence = element.textContent.trim();
        localStorage.setItem('sentence', sentence);
        window.open('/explanation.html', '_blank');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="showExplanation(this)">Sentence 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showExplanation(this)">Sentence 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showExplanation(this)">Sentence 3</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Explanation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Loading...</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const sentence = localStorage.getItem('sentence');

      fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer API_KEY' // replace with your API key
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'prompt': 'What does this sentence mean? ' + sentence,
          'temperature': 0.5,
          'max_tokens': 50
        })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(output => {
          const explanation = output.choices[0].text.trim();
          const pElement = document.createElement('p');
          pElement.textContent = explanation;
          document.body.innerHTML = '';
          document.body.appendChild(pElement);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2:

I've redone the script so that the need for the separate explanation.html page is dropped and it instead displays the output from the OpenAI API in an alert box that pops up in index.html.

Here is the new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function showExplanation(element) {
        const sentence = element.textContent.trim();

        fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_API_KEY'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            prompt: "What does this sentence mean? " + sentence,
            max_tokens: 128,
            temperature: 0.5
          })
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(output => {
            const explanation = output.choices[0].text.trim();
            alert(explanation);
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="showExplanation(this)">When push comes to shove in a situation defined by opposition deemed as evil according to the way the opponent dismisses any honor you show you must not expect that what corners you will let up for any premature retreat you make becomes bound to come back as a weakened ability to fight off attacks made on you.</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm now getting a response from the OpenAI API however the response is incoherent and does not make sense and doesn't compare to the response outputted from GPT4 when using the same prompt (What does this sentence mean? + "sentence"). I've included an example sentence that gets posted to the OpenAI API for reference when debugging.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled why you use two HTML pages? And why would you use `fetch` to open the second page? If you really need to pass the sentence from the first page to the second page, I think using `localStorage` would be much easier. The first page can do `localstorage.setItem("sentence", sentence)`. Then the second page can read that sentence and do the API call.

Comment: I tried using localStorage to pass the sentence to explanation.html however I am still getting a static "Loading..." and no dynamic explanation from the OpenAI API. New code above. Any thoughts?

Comment: FYI, tags are text in a file. You're describing _elements_ here, which are what the browser renders.

Answer (score 0):

For me the connection works when I test with a simple prompt. To test if OpenAI works at all, you can just test with a basic prompt.

If it doesn't work for you, what is the error message you get in the console?

To focus on one problem at a time, just ignore the localStorage and DOM manipulation for now, and first get `fetch` working in a console message. If that works, you can fix the other two.

I used a slightly different url than in your code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        const sentence = "can you create a recipe for salad and fries?"
        const url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions";
        const bearer = 'Bearer ' + 'yourkeyhere'

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': bearer
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'prompt': sentence,
                'temperature': 0.5,
                'max_tokens': 50
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(output => {
                console.log(output)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    </script>
```

Comment: I replaced the API url with the link you provided and am now getting a response from the API. No error messages anywhere. However, the response is garbled and makes no sense. It doesn't compare to the output produced by GPT4 chat using the same prompt. Any thoughts?

Comment: I actually edited the code so that the separate explanation.html is no longer required by opting for the output to be displayed in an alert box instead. See above for the new code. Still on the same issue: incoherent response from the OpenAI API.

Comment: That means at least your side of the code is working :) Have you tried default settings from the documentation? https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests And what output do you get exactly?

Comment: Which default setting are you referring to? Currently using the completions request using the url you provided. The response I'm getting from the example sentence provided just shows the prompt question + the sentence itself repeated multiple times over.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the text explanations working with the following code for anyone interested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function showExplanation(element) {
        const apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
        const apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";

        const prompt = element.textContent.trim();

        fetch(apiUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${apiKey}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            messages: [
              { role: "system", content: "What does this sentence mean?" },
              { role: "user", content: prompt }
            ],
            max_tokens: 1024,
            temperature: 0.2,
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo"
          })
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(output => {
            const explanation = output.choices[0].message.content;
            alert(explanation);
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p onclick="showExplanation(this)">When push comes to shove in a situation defined by opposition deemed as evil according to the way the opponent dismisses any honor you show you must not expect that what corners you will let up for any premature retreat you make becomes bound to come back as a weakened ability to fight off attacks made on you.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```